# How to load an image in kivy?

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

My code:

.py file:

```
class Picture(Image):
    pass

class blablabla(HatWidget):
    ...
    self.add_widget(Picture(sourse='paper.png'))
```

.kv file:

```
<Picture>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: (1, 1, 1)
        Rectangle:
            texture: self.texture
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
```

But only thing I have is a white screen

Comment: can you make a runnable example? here ... can mean a lot, and you can't just do add_widget out of any method here, it's something that has to be done in an instance, not the class.

Answer (score 2):

i'm pretty sure Image property to set the image is `source` not `sourse`.

Also, you'll likely want to remove the base rule if you want to display the image yourself.

<-Picture>

the "-" will tell kv to drop the rule inherited from Image.

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is that its a fullscreen, white canvas. So if its just a blank white screen, that would be the expected output. Or at least according to the kivy documentation you copied this from as far as I can see.